# Ubuntu keyboard backlight problem on Dell Vostro 5568, on battery works normally, on AC behaves strangely

Tags: backlight, keyboard-backlight

My problem is that Ubuntu turns off the keyboard backlight automatically after 1 second or less if I didn't touch the touchpad, when running on AC.

On battery it works normally (and Ubuntu waits 1 minute to turn it off).

Any ideas how to repair and solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 17.04 on my Dell Vostro 5468. Has resolved by upgrading BIOS firmware to 1.1.1.
This can be done in a few steps:
1.Prepare USB drive via Gparted (format fat32) and Unetbootin (select freedos in the list of distros).
2. Eject the USB drive, then re-insert it so you can see the new FreeDOS file system.
3. Copy your BIOS update file to the drive.
4. Reboot, press F12 for the one-time boot menu, and boot from the USB Storage Device.
5. Choose "fdos".
6. Choose "4 - Load FreeDOS without drivers."
7. Execute the BIOS update.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain how to do this

Comment: I have followed this instruction https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DellBIOS under section "Upgrading with a FreeDOS USB drive". USB drive I have prepared via Gparted (format fat32) and Unetbootin.

Comment: yes, but please could you add that information to your question, so that visitors don't have to go to an external site and can do everything required just by following your instructions?